# How to get build times of individual targets with bazel?

Tags: bazel

We have a bunch of targets being built by Bazel in our build environment today, targets being `cc_binary`/`cc_test`/`cc_library` etc. Is there some Bazel option that dumps build time for each of these into a file so we can analyze it after the build is done. While building Bazel dumps some timing information that disappears fast but I am looking for something (either text/XML or any other readable format) that can be used in post-build analysis.

Answer (score 2):

To some extent this is possible. Look at the documentation: [Performance profiling](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/performance.html#performance-profiling)

There is the build flag `--experimental_generate_json_trace_profile` that generates a file named `command.profile.gz` in our `outputBase` dir (details about the outputBase dir can be fond [here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/output_directories.html)).

Example:

```
bazel build --experimental_generate_json_trace_profile --experimental_profile_cpu_usage //:HelloWorld
```

`command.profile.gz` contains a file named `command.profile`. This can be view in Chrome (`chrome://tracing/`).

[image]

(Tested with Bazel 2.0.0)